# Why do I still see a bottom border in my Google CSE results?

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-custom-search

I'm using V1 GCSE code to display search results on a Wordpress site with a Genesis child theme.

Most of the styling is going okay, but for the life of me, **I can't figure out where these thin gray bottom borders are coming from:**
[image: search results page with borders]

The staging site with a test query can be found at http://74.220.217.211/search/?q=test

Please help me figure out why I still see borders! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some things that haven't worked: `#search-results table.gsc-table-result { border-bottom: none !important; }` and `#search-results div.gsc-result {  border-bottom: none !important; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Chrome, the HTML has a <tbody> tag dynamically inserted between the <table> and <tr> tags. This <tbody> tag is the one still holding onto the border.

You'll need to update the rule in style.css to include <tbody>, eg:

```
#search-results table, #search-results table tr, #search-results table tr td {
    ...
    border: 0 none;
}
```

becomes

```
#search-results table, #search-results table tr, #search-results table tr td, #search-results table tbody {
    ...
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Hallelujah! Thanks so much, Jeremy.

Comment: No problem - it actually had me stumped too for a bit!

Comment: Note, you say "at least in Chrome", but _all_ browsers do this. It's part of the formal definition of HTML, so if any browser wouldn't insert a tbody, that would be a serious bug!

Comment: I guess I mean "I've tested in Chrome, but assume no responsibility for this working or not working in IE6."

Answer (score 0):

well I hope this solves your problem

**.gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover, .gsc-imageResult:hover**

at http://74.220.217.211/search/?q=test line 196

remove this

```
border-color: #8DBCB0;
border-width: 3px;
```

**.cse .gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover, .gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover, .gsc-webResult.gsc-result.gsc-promotion:hover, .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult-classic:hover, .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult-column:hover**

at https://cse.google.com/cse/style/look/minimalist.css line 165

remove this

```
border-left: 1px solid;
border-color: #000000;
border-bottom: 0px solid;
```

"The print shows how I get this information"

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

As the author now specified that is the gray border he wants to remove - It came from http://74.220.217.211/search/?q=test line 464
tbody { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }

This last print shows the code

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should have been clearer in my original post. I've updated it to explain that it's the thin gray bottom borders that I'm concerned about, not the blue-green left border that appears on hover (that's intentional). Were you able to get the bottom border to disappear when you were playing in your browser?

Comment: I just updated my answer, check out if it solves your problem :]